# Authenticating my request using Basic Auth but it keeps responding with an Unauthorized message?

Tags: java, api, messaging

```
String name = "xyz";
  String password = "xyz";
  String authString = name + ":" + password;
  String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
  static String URL = "https://api.messagemedia.com";
  String getURI = "/v1/replies";
  static String postURI = "/v1/replies/confirmed";
  static Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
  public Data getRequest() {
        Response response = (Response) client.target(URL + getURI).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    .header("Accept", "application/json").header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc).get();
}
```

I'm sure I've configured it right but I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong."

Answer (score 0):

MessageMedia Developer Evangelist here.

I think you might be assigning bytes to a String variable. Give this a shot:

```
String name = "kD4ub2gYkvO82mGYidRU";
String password = "iOwj2pbhwB8Ukqu4hgKmCSUSi8bzVB";
String authString = name + ":" + password;
byte[] authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
String authStringConv = new String(authStringEnc);
static String URL = "https://api.messagemedia.com";
String getURI = "/v1/replies";
static String postURI = "/v1/replies/confirmed";
static Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
public Data getRequest() {
      Response response = (Response) client.target(URL + getURI).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).header("Content-Type", "application/json").header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringConv).get();
}
```